# Изменение высоты iframe после загрузки

Tags: html, javascript, iframe

После загрузки `<iframe>`, в котором расположена гостевая книга (взятая со стороннего сервиса), необходимо изменить размер `<iframe>`, так чтобы полоса прокрутки на странице была одна, а не две: на `<iframe>` и на самой странице.

Как реализовать функцию примерно такого содержания:

1. После загрузки `iframe` узнать его высоту `X`.
2. Изменить старую высоту `iframe` на `X`.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос множество раз решался: [1](http://habrahabr.ru/post/78702/), [2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/78845/), [3](http://www.askdev.ru/javascript/8443/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-iframe-height/). Ответ устроит или ещё нужны решения?

Как на счёт ещё версии? [Редактирование только из родительского документа](http://yanke.ru/post/crossdomain-iframe-height/).

Comment: Первую ссылку я посмотрел, но там приводится решения для случая, когда на вставляемой странице находится "какой угодно код, полностью нам подвластный" (цитата из первой ссылки). А доступа к стороннему сервису, который предоставляет гостевую книгу, я не имею. Поэтому, к сожалению, такое решение не подходит. У меня есть только ссылка, которая подгружается в iframe.
Вторая ссылка тоже требует, чтобы "Во включаемую страницу с домена slave.site в head добавляем ссылку на жаваскрипт http://master.site/iframe_height.js", т.е. опять не подходит.

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: @Gurylev, @Alexey7wolf

> без доступа к источнику, который подключается в iframe, нельзя отслеживать из родительского окна изменение его высоты

в общем нельзя, это вопрос безопасности.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Кажется, без доступа к исходному документу высоты его для фрейма не получить... Я думал, что если объект загружается на мою страницу, то логично предположить, что браузер по факту загрузки сможет определить высоту уже загруженного элемента и тут же изменить высоту фрейма. Ну, или по крайней мере, не сильно промедлит с изменением :)

Comment: @АндрийГурылёв Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).